# iphone Autorefresh - updating the view by maintaining the scroll position

Tags: iphone

I am developing a cricket app where there is autorefresh. We use a framework library which handles the autorefresh and layouting of views. The problem is that during autorefresh the data is got, the view is created , and the existing view is removed and replaced. Because of this, the scroll position is not maintained and the page scrolls to the top.

How can this be avoided. Hope am clear about my requirement. The problem is also that the data is dynamic and the layout has to be flexible.

Answer (score 0):

can't you store the scroll position every time the user scrolls and on data refresh (when the new view is create) scroll the new view to that location. If the new view is smaller(cannot scroll to that position) then you can either take to the top or bottom of the view.

Comment: I know this is one way of doing but it will be more visible to the user when he scrolls. I know that I have to update the same view instance, instead of re-creating the views. But, the issue is the data in the view can change dynamically as well as the height of the view.